# Setup an expectation or mock for a class using AutoMockContainer

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, moq, moqcontrib

I am using AutoMockContainer (https://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking) of Moq.Contrib to create an instance of a concrete type and satisfy its dependencies automatically. The problem is that I want to create a setup on the T returned by AutoMockContanier.Create. I need Mock for it but Create returns T? Sample code below (and also here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sa1jCq ) -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Moq;

namespace AutoMoqTest
{
    public interface ICustomerValidator
    {
        bool IsAdult(int age);
    }

    public class CustomerValidator:ICustomerValidator
    {

        public bool IsAdult(int age)
        {
            return age >= 18;
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        private ICustomerValidator CustomerValidator { get; set; }
        public Customer(ICustomerValidator customerValidator)
        {
            CustomerValidator = customerValidator;
        }

        public int CustomerAge { get { return 10; } }

        public bool IsCustomerAdult()
        {
            return CustomerValidator.IsAdult(CustomerAge);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class DITest
    {
        [Test]
        public void IsAdult_should_be_true_for_customer_having_age_20()
        {
            var factory = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Loose);
            var container = new AutoMockContainer(factory);
            //var customer = container.Create<Customer>();
            var customerMock = container.GetMock<Customer>();
            customerMock.Setup(x=>x.CustomerAge).Returns(20); //NEED TO ACHIEVE THIS SETUP
           // Assert.IsTrue(customer.IsCustomerAdult());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should investigate github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture - its a proper grown up well-maintained equivalent of AutoMockContainer

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have made things complicated. You really don't need Auto Mocking. If you want to get the best out of Unit Testing, keep it simple and importantly test things in isolation. Just write a test for CustomerValidator

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomerValidatorTest
{

    [Test]
    public void IsAdult_should_be_true_for_customer_having_age_20()
    {
        var sut = new CustomerValidator();            
        int greaterThanAge = 20;

        var result = sut.IsAdult(greaterThanAge);

        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}
```

If you really want to test the Customer, then write another test

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomerTests
{

    [Test]
    public void IsCustomerAdult_verifyIsAdultIsCalled()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ICustomerValidator>();
        var sut = new Customer(mock.Object);

        var result = sut.IsCustomerAdult();

        mock.Verify(x => x.IsAdult(It.IsAny<int>()));
    }
}
```

You don't need AutoMocking in such trivial tests.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear enough. AutoMockContainer is not by choice but an existing implementation which I am open to change if something better can be used. Also, the example above is a very simplified view of my actual problem. I have a set of dependencies being injected in a chain of calls. Though I will attempt at rethinking and simplifying my approach but the scenario I provided should be simpler looking at it.